# Renaming parameters in nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 4.2.6, I am creating nested resources like this

routes.rb:

```
resources :analysis, param: :project_id do 
  resources :configuration 
end

resources :decision, param: :project_id do
  resources :configuration
end
```

It works fine when I am in the analysis or decision controller. However, when I am in the configuration controller, I receive the param `:analysis_project_id` or `:decision_project_id`. How can I change this so I still receive `:project_id`?

I don't want to customize my configuration controller to be aware that it is nested in different resources.

Answer (score 1):

just this, you need not to send `params` over here, It will take automatically with corresponding to your `action`.

```
  resources :analysis do 
       resources :configuration  
  end
```

if you need routes like these

```
 analysis_configuration_index GET       /analysis/:analysis_id/configuration(.:format)          configuration#index
                              POST      /analysis/:analysis_id/configuration(.:format)          configuration#create
 new_analysis_configuration GET       /analysis/:analysis_id/configuration/new(.:format)      configuration#new
 edit_analysis_configuration GET       /analysis/:analysis_id/configuration/:id/edit(.:format) configuration#edit
 analysis_configuration GET       /analysis/:analysis_id/configuration/:id(.:format)      configuration#show
                         PATCH     /analysis/:analysis_id/configuration/:id(.:format)      configuration#update
                         PUT       /analysis/:analysis_id/configuration/:id(.:format)      configuration#update
                         DELETE    /analysis/:analysis_id/configuration/:id(.:format)      configuration#destroy
          analysis_index GET       /analysis(.:format)                                     analysis#index
                         POST      /analysis(.:format)                                     analysis#create
            new_analysis GET       /analysis/new(.:format)                                 analysis#new
           edit_analysis GET       /analysis/:id/edit(.:format)                            analysis#edit
                analysis GET       /analysis/:id(.:format)                                 analysis#show
                         PATCH     /analysis/:id(.:format)                                 analysis#update
                         PUT       /analysis/:id(.:format)                                 analysis#update
                         DELETE    /analysis/:id(.:format)                                 analysis#destroy
```

**EDITED 13 Aug 2020**

To get the specific param in nested resources

```
resources :analysis, param: :project_id do
   member do
        resources :configurations
   end
end
resources :decision, param: :project_id do
  member do
     resources :configurations
  end
end
```

Expected routes

```
    configurations GET      /analysis/:project_id/configurations(.:format)                                     configurations#index
              POST     /analysis/:project_id/configurations(.:format)                                     configurations#create
new_configuration GET      /analysis/:project_id/configurations/new(.:format)                                 configurations#new
edit_configuration GET      /analysis/:project_id/configurations/:id/edit(.:format)                            configurations#edit
    configuration GET      /analysis/:project_id/configurations/:id(.:format)                                 configurations#show
                  PATCH    /analysis/:project_id/configurations/:id(.:format)                                 configurations#update
                  PUT      /analysis/:project_id/configurations/:id(.:format)                                 configurations#update
                  DELETE   /analysis/:project_id/configurations/:id(.:format)                                 configurations#destroy
   analysis_index GET      /analysis(.:format)                                                                analysis#index
                  POST     /analysis(.:format)                                                                analysis#create
     new_analysis GET      /analysis/new(.:format)                                                            analysis#new
    edit_analysis GET      /analysis/:project_id/edit(.:format)                                               analysis#edit
         analysis GET      /analysis/:project_id(.:format)                                                    analysis#show
                  PATCH    /analysis/:project_id(.:format)                                                    analysis#update
                  PUT      /analysis/:project_id(.:format)                                                    analysis#update
                  DELETE   /analysis/:project_id(.:format)                                                    analysis#destroy
                  GET      /decisions/:project_id/configurations(.:format)                                    configurations#index
                  POST     /decisions/:project_id/configurations(.:format)                                    configurations#create
                  GET      /decisions/:project_id/configurations/new(.:format)                                configurations#new
                  GET      /decisions/:project_id/configurations/:id/edit(.:format)                           configurations#edit
                  GET      /decisions/:project_id/configurations/:id(.:format)                                configurations#show
                  PATCH    /decisions/:project_id/configurations/:id(.:format)                                configurations#update
                  PUT      /decisions/:project_id/configurations/:id(.:format)                                configurations#update
                  DELETE   /decisions/:project_id/configurations/:id(.:format)                                configurations#destroy
        decisions GET      /decisions(.:format)                                                               decisions#index
                  POST     /decisions(.:format)                                                               decisions#create
     new_decision GET      /decisions/new(.:format)                                                           decisions#new
    edit_decision GET      /decisions/:project_id/edit(.:format)                                              decisions#edit
         decision GET      /decisions/:project_id(.:format)                                                   decisions#show
                  PATCH    /decisions/:project_id(.:format)                                                   decisions#update
                  PUT      /decisions/:project_id(.:format)                                                   decisions#update
                  DELETE   /decisions/:project_id(.:format)                                                   decisions#destroy
```

Comment: With this, I have the parameter `:id` in the analysis controller, which is renamed to `:analysis_id` in the configuration controller. I want the same parameter name in both.

Comment: May I ask why you want the same parameter name, as it is accessible to both of the controller.

Comment: Because the configuration controller will be nested in several resources, and the `:project_id` will be different each time, preventing me to write generic code.